# react-virtualized onRowsRendered placeholder

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I am using react-virtualized Table. I want to add placeholder while rendering rows looking like this on onRowsRendered InfiniteLoader. Can I use this kind of data placeholder when working on prefetched data?

[image]

[RESOLVE]
To reduce user distraction I added a css animation to ReactVirtualized__Table__row class

```
@keyframes showRow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.ReactVirtualized__Table__row {
    animation: 0.8s 0s 1 showRow;
}
```

Comment: If you already have data, why do you need a placeholder?

Comment: Because rendering of complex rows takes too long and user see white space for a while and then jump in data which can be distracting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm glad you found a CSS solution. Just so you know, you can accomplish your original goal using JavaScript as well by specifying a custom [`rowRenderer`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Table.md#rowrenderer) for your `Table`.

```
import { defaultTableRowRenderer, Table } from 'react-virtualized'

function renderTable (props) {
  return (
    <Table
      rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
      {...props}
    />
  )
}

function rowRenderer (props) {
  if (props.isScrolling) {
    return (
      <YourScrollPlaceholderWidget
        key={props.key}
        style={props.style}
      />
    )
  } else {
    return defaultTableRowRenderer(props)
  }
}
```